# Django test freeze at database creation

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

It's my first attempt in Unit testing with Django, and it's not going well...

I've got something really weird. When I launch the tests with: ./manage.py test, the command line freezes on "Creating test database for alias 'default'...". I've wait 10min, and nothing... Impossible to cancel (CTRL+C) the thing. I have to close the shell and start over.

If I "runserver" the application, everything works. I saw that it's creating a database named "test_" with all the tables, but stop right after, without prompting any error or something.

Somebody have an idea about all this ?

Comment: more code or context would be helpful

Comment: What DB engine? Have you tried to test whole suite or one separate app? Do you have south enabled for tests?

Comment: The DB is MySQL. I tried to call a separate app (swingtime, which should have well built tests). South is enabled. Is there a way to disable it in test mode ?

Comment: If I remove South from the installed Apps, it works ! But I'm using South for migrations. Is there a way to know in settings.py if we're in test mode or not ? I could remove south if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's finally working !

The problem came from South. If South is in the INSTALLED_APPS, without the setting "SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False", it freezes while creating the test database. Maybe it's just taking too much time to execute, but I've waited more than 15min, and it stays freezed.

Here's the documentation about this:
http://south.aeracode.org/docs/settings.html#south-tests-migrate

Comment: This currently is pissing me off, I am not even using South at all. :|

Comment: For me it was my `Mysql` server that was acting up, on restarting Mysql it works fine.